Verify signature with C/OpenSSL
I generated a key pair in PHP using:
$options = [
    'digest_alg' => 'SHA256',
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_EC,
    'private_key_bits' => 2048,
    'curve_name' => 'secp384r1'];

Which gave me:
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MHYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEACIDYgAEieSNdLKtNPdLIo9Y+f1DTfjnpZ4NFMXc
qVV2epFEWdtCyzhZnMubQDtpmhcycVZM+aPELe0dVWvwkFAY+VO0SpLT4I+cVkar
FSkjtp84jWZsWj8DT+7S0ukoEJzraeff
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGkAgEBBDAUQuV5RcleR29UgIK0bjczEHctb6TK5z3PesxjT2R8A3B7iQDl0/I9
bkFjLyMYyFOgBwYFK4EEACKhZANiAASJ5I10sq0090sij1j5/UNN+Oelng0Uxdyp
VXZ6kURZ20LLOFmcy5tAO2maFzJxVkz5o8Qt7R1Va/CQUBj5U7RKktPgj5xWRqsV
KSO2nziNZmxaPwNP7tLS6SgQnOtp598=
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----

msg: Hello World!

sig: MGYCMQDa3+Nz6zxJOkvLjI2AVFXb4zfoYuFzy79Hg2bKq3El93oQwNleUgV
k1TuS8ptSj5kCMQCYVyplp5/yoCBLQpwsQw+MKlJ78ncQgiyh9UIBOFHTQvMjWiZ
BvOQ/B0VsZY7xoeo=

How do I read the public key in C/OpenSSL and check if the signature is correct? I can't find the right command in the OpenSSL Documentation.

Hard to believe that you have not found any examples for key import or verification. Anyway, here is an example of the key import: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78428145/9014097, and here you can find an example for verifying: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying#Verifying.

The examples helped. I think it wasn't working because of the base64 conversion to binary, and the '=' characters. Here is a working example:
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/decoder.h>

void errors() {
    int r;
    char error[256];
    while ((r = ERR_get_error()) != 0) {
        ERR_error_string_n(r, error, 256);
        std::cout << "Error " << r << ": " << error << "\n";
    }
}

int pubKeyFromPem(EVP_PKEY** pkey, const unsigned char* data, size_t datalen) {
    const char* keytype = "EC";
    int selection = OSSL_KEYMGMT_SELECT_PUBLIC_KEY;
    OSSL_DECODER_CTX* dctx = OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey(pkey, "PEM", NULL, keytype, selection, NULL, NULL);
    if (dctx == NULL) {
        return __LINE__;
    }
    if (!OSSL_DECODER_from_data(dctx, &data, &datalen)) {
        return __LINE__;
    }
    OSSL_DECODER_CTX_free(dctx);
    return 0;
}

int base64ToSig(const char* sig64, int sig64len, unsigned char** sig, size_t* siglen) {
    int memory = sig64len / 4 * 3;
    *sig = (unsigned char*)malloc(memory);
    if (*sig == NULL)
        return __LINE__;
    int len = EVP_DecodeBlock(*sig, (const unsigned char*)sig64, sig64len);
    if (len == -1)
        return __LINE__;
    if (sig64[sig64len - 1] == '=')
        len--;
    if (sig64[sig64len - 2] == '=')
        len--;
    *siglen = len;
    return 0;
}

int verify(EVP_PKEY* key, const char* msg, unsigned char* sig, size_t siglen) {
    EVP_MD_CTX* mdctx;
    if (!(mdctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create()))
        return __LINE__;
    if (1 != EVP_DigestVerifyInit(mdctx, NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL, key))
        return __LINE__;
    if (1 != EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(mdctx, msg, strlen(msg)))
        return __LINE__;
    int r = EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(mdctx, sig, siglen);
    if (1 == r) {
        std::cout << "Success!\n";
    } else if (0 == r) {
        std::cout << "Failure!\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error!\n";
        errors();
    }
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(mdctx);
    return 0;
}

int check() {
    int line;
    const char* msg = "Hello World!";
    const char* pubKeyPem =
        "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
        "MHYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEACIDYgAEQl0DmsjriyNARf16wXp8+S3qEkwKHOl4\n"
        "0kSfEo48e67oF03vjUyWKVl/FMnjpzMV9O6UpKUAR19svqJwa6iihhbBRU9PsfGO\n"
        "dGgCwedB85QrwtlJ9UZSrYQ93r9tUha3\n"
        "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    const char* sig64 =
        "MGYCMQDkL/SH5FKGJSUkEWUhUgwvVTgQUg3jd49280/oTuu+EuwNzFiHhKo"
        "NXAeDqzW8r+4CMQDPVRoKGRI/a7qSZQZQuHFmh5kK9Wp9wY2+dvLb/4lCrW+PHM8"
        "Vs0S+ORkp1uoMUDY=";
    unsigned char* sig;
    size_t siglen;

    EVP_PKEY* key = NULL;
    line = pubKeyFromPem(&key, (const unsigned char*)pubKeyPem, strlen(pubKeyPem));
    if (line != 0)
        return line;
    line = base64ToSig(sig64, strlen(sig64), &sig, &siglen);
    if (line != 0)
        return line;
    std::cout << "Verifying with PEM key: ";
    line = verify(key, msg, sig, siglen);
    if (line != 0)
        return line;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int line = check();
    if (line != 0) {
        std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << line << "\n";
        errors();
    }
}

